# problem redefining weak functions in embedded cpp

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, bare-metal

Problem: I defined two weak functions in "startup.cpp" which, both are also the alias for one function called `Default_Handler` defined in the same file. Even though I'm prototyping the `Default_Handler` function correctly, I'm getting an undefined symbol error.

```
void Default_Handler(void);

 __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);
 __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);

void Default_Handler(void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

error log:

```
 error: 'void EXTI0_IRQHandler()' aliased to undefined symbol 'Default_Handler'
   21 | __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")))void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);

error: 'void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler()' aliased to undefined symbol 'Default_Handler'
   22 | __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")))void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);
```

This error does not make any sense to me since the target function (`Default_Handler`) is correctly defined.

I guess it has something to do with name mangling in C++, but I actually have no idea how to deal with this. So help would be really appreciated.

What I actually need is the possibility to overwrite `void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)` and `void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)` from another cpp file: let's say I have a `main.cpp` file, in which I need to overwrite those functions. If there is any other way than using weak attribute, that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the name mangling.

`void Default_Handler(void)` in C++ is `?Default_Handler@@YAXXZ` in the object file (in Assembler). You should use the mangled names when aliasing:

```
void Default_Handler(void);

 __attribute__((weak, alias("_Z15Default_Handlerv"))) void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);
 __attribute__((weak, alias("_Z15Default_Handlerv"))) void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);

void Default_Handler(void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

Or make the old name `extern "C"`

```
extern "C" void Default_Handler(void);

 __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);
 __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);

void Default_Handler(void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

You can get mangled names using `-Xlinker --no-demangle` linker options.

You do not need declarations, since the aliasing happens on the linkage stage. This works also:

```
 __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);
 __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);

extern "C" void Default_Handler(void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: I've solved the problem by doing:

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <stdint.h>


int main(void);
void Reset_Handler(void);
void Default_Handler(void);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif